# Import a jar file into flutter android plugin and use it in android studio 3.6.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter

I imported a JAR file by creating `libs` folder in my project roots -> copy and pasted the `JAR` file into the `libs` folder -> right click on the `JAR` file and click `Add As Library`. How do I use the imported `JAR` in my code? the `JAR` file is `xxx.jar`. 
Thanks.

Comment: did you got the answer im stuck in this too. .

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify what jar it is exactly?

Other than that you can call it at the top of your code by typing

"import XYZ.XYZ.XYZ" replace with the folder name and name of your jar etc.

You can also go to File > Project Structure > Dependencies and below Declared dependencies you can add your jar file.

Comment: I don't really understand what you meant by "Declaring what JAR it is".
The JAR file is an SDK for a Android POS Device. I hope this answer your question. 

my JAR file is already in the "Declared dependencies" list.

This is the `path` to the JAR file: `libs/gprintersdkv22.jar`

am i to import it this way: `import libs.gprintersdkv22;` ?

my .java file path is : `src/main/java/com.dy.mlsflutterplugin/MlsflutterpluginPlugin.java`

Comment: @user3867365 did you got the answer , i am stuck in that too !

Answer (score 0):

I add my SDK to libs folder in android folder and than:

1. Select the android folder from your project
2. Right-click on it, go to -> Flutter -> Open project in android studio.
3. Go to File->Project Strucuture-> Dependencies.
4. Select the name of plugin (you should ad dependency here, not in app or All Modules)
5. Click on the "+" button to add a new dependency

after that you can import your classes in your plugin.

Comment: my Flutter button on right click is disabled :(